# Why won't my simple YQL JSON-via-Jquery script parse in internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, parsing, yql

I've got my scribd xml feed (with its secret pass key hidden) converted to JSON via YQL.

I want to use jQuery to populate an unordered list with the results. It's working in everything but IE.

This seems pretty barebones to me, and yet I can't understand why it achieves nothing in Internet Explorer. There must be some IE secret I don't know about, like JSON is handled differently in IE, or you need to use JSONP, or IE doesn't play nice with this usage of .each()... What am I missing here? Here's a jFiddle Link to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/niceindividual/nRkvS/2/

```
var yqlURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql/dulyb/scribdCHF?format=json";
window.console.log("The yqlURL variable is set to " + yqlURL);

$.getJSON(yqlURL, function(data) {
    $.each(data.query.results.result, function() {
        $('#results').append('<li><div><a href=\"http://www.scribd.com/doc/' + this.doc_id + '\">' + '<img src=\"' + this.thumbnail_url + '\" />' + '<span>' + this.title + '</span></div></a><p>' + this.description + '</p></li>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is window.console.log available?  Try a javascript alert() instead.

Comment: window.console.log works in IE8. I had alerts earlier which worked too. It still fails in IE8 without console or alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend Raymon helped me out:

`YQL` outputs `JSONP`, not `JSON;` so in the code above, I used `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON` and set the `dataType` to "`jsonp`". It seems to work in IE now.

Updated (fixed) Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niceindividual/nRkvS/4/